# imagemagick installed local but composer update doesn't run. OSX

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php, mamp

I just finished installing imagemagick through brew but composer update still says it is not installed. What is the problem?

Do I need to have MAMP or XAMPP opened and running when I run composer update or it doesn't matter?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: would be better to replace the screenshot with the actual textual representation of the error message.

Comment: Did you read the error? `ext-imagick is missing from your system`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `Imagick` class in PHP you need to install both Imagemagick console tool and library **and** ext-imagick — php extension: [PECL imagick](http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick)

You just need to install PHP extension (in addition to Imagemagick you have installed already). In general yon need to run `pecl install imagick`. Please read [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/imagick.installation.php) for details

In case of using MAMP if you haven't setup it's directory into $PATH you need to enter full path to MAMP's pecl. For details refer this artile [Installing PHP PEAR and PECL extensions on MAMP for Mac OS X](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/installing-php-pear-and-pecl-extensions-on-mamp-for-mac-os-x-107-lion)

No, you don't need MAMP to be running. On the contrary you need to restart httpd after any php.ini changes.

Comment: I'm not understanding what I should do on that site. I'm on OSX by the way, I see a lot of windows icons in there...

I didn't know I was making changed to any php.ini, I'm just trying to install that thing so that I can run composer update. This is a nightmare

Comment: You just need to install PHP extension (in addition to Imagemagick you have installed already). In general yon need to run `pecl install imagick` Please read PHP manual for details http://php.net/manual/imagick.installation.php

Comment: Also you can refer this article about installing PECL extension on MAMP under OS X https://www.lullabot.com/articles/installing-php-pear-and-pecl-extensions-on-mamp-for-mac-os-x-107-lion